# Based on one input value,populate table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can i achieve this, I want the orange table to be auto generated, based on the value in cell "F5" i.e minutes earned more than : '410'....
F5=410

I tried using index, match but couldn't achieve.Can someone help.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this is E8, drag over to F8, and then drag both down as far as needed.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$6:$C$21)/($C$6:$C$21>=$F$5),ROW()-7),1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate you response, but this doesnt work :(.. IT just gave me one row that is k.. i need it for all the instances (can have many associate names)

Comment: @Ruchi I added a screenshot to show it working in my spreadsheet. I edited the formula a couple of times, so perhaps you got a version before the last edit?

Comment: oh yes,  works but doesnt pick all the rows, skipped first two rows in Col 'B', i tried to put same data in C6 and C7.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($E10,$B$6:$C$21,1,FALSE)<$F$5,"",VLOOKUP($E10,$B$6:$C$21,1,FALSE)),0)
```

But if you want to display only the one matching the criteria within continuous rows, you'll need at least a column helper storing the row coming from `MATCH`.

Comment: Doesnt help, Shows 0 :(

Answer (score 0):

You could add a helper-column and put:

```
=SMALL(IF(C:C<=$F$5,ROW(C:C)),ROW())
```

then push ctrl+shift+enter and drag down in column D. Then use `=INDEX(B:D,D2,1)` add `IFERROR`to avoid #errors